# Deleted vcs.xml file when updating git due to conflict issues and my program stopped working

Tags: javascript, php, git

I managed to delete my vcs.xml file from my project because of conflicts when pushing to git. Now my code has completely stopped working and nothing shows up in the browser console. Is there anyway to get this file back?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever committed that file at some point?

Comment: It's committed to git the .idea folder and vcs.xml but I can't get it back from there because when I download whats saved to git the .idea folder isn't there.